# Why docker push registry errors on certificate file?

Tags: docker, ssl-certificate, docker-registry, self-signed, apparmor

As described here [How to setup docker private registry on ubuntu 16.04](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/how-to-setup-docker-private-registry-on-ubuntu-16-04_594085),

I changed `/etc/hosts` like this:

```
192.168.1.154 registry-server
192.168.1.90 registry-client
```

Then I pulled the registry image:

```
docker pull registry
```

Then I made certificate files

```
mkdir /etc/certs
cd /etc/certs
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha256 -keyout ca.key -x509 -days 365 -out ca.crt
```

I copied the `ca.crt` to these pathes in client host:

```
/etc/certs/
/etc/docker/certs.d/registry-server:5000/
```

Then I ran the container on the server host:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry -v /etc/certs:/etc/certs -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/etc/certs/ca.crt -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/etc/certs/ca.key registry
```

I tagged the image

```
docker tag phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest registry-server:5000/pma-test
```

But when I want to push the image `registry-server:5000/pma-test` to the server:

```
docker push registry-server:5000/pma-test:latest
```

The following error occurs:

> Error response from daemon: open /etc/docker/certs.d/registry-server:5000: permission denied

======================================

Update:

I ran `journalctl -xe`, and found these errors:

> Sep 30 13:58:37 docker.dockerd[926]: time="2019-09-30T13:58:37.229097561Z" level=debug msg="Calling GET /_ping"
>
> Sep 30 13:58:37 docker.dockerd[926]: time="2019-09-30T13:58:37.238248010Z" level=debug msg="Calling POST /v1.38/images/registry-server:5000/pma-test/push?tag="
>
> Sep 30 13:58:37 docker.dockerd[926]: time="2019-09-30T13:58:37.238670117Z" level=debug msg="hostDir: /etc/docker/certs.d/registry-server:5000"
>
> Sep 30 13:58:37 docker.dockerd[926]: time="2019-09-30T13:58:37.238797277Z" level=debug msg="FIXME: Got an API for which error does not match any expected type!!!: open /etc/docker/certs.d/registry-server:5000: permission denied" error_type="*os.PathError" module=api
>
> Sep 30 13:58:37 docker.dockerd[926]: time="2019-09-30T13:58:37.238831133Z" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.38/images/registry-server:5000/pma-test/push returned error: open /etc/docker/certs.d/registry-server:5000: permission denied"
>
> Sep 30 13:58:37 docker.dockerd[926]: time="2019-09-30T13:58:37.238861895Z" level=debug msg="FIXME: Got an API for which error does not match any expected type!!!: open /etc/docker/certs.d/registry-server:5000: permission denied" error_type="*os.PathError" module=api
>
> Sep 30 13:58:37 audit[926]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.docker.dockerd" name="/etc/docker/certs.d/registry-server:5000/" pid=926 comm="dockerd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
>
> Sep 30 13:58:37 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1569851917.234:53): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.docker.dockerd" name="/etc/docker/certs.d/registry-server:5000/" pid=926 comm="dockerd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0

Why did this error happen?

**Docker version 19.03.2, build 6a30dfc**

**docker-compose version 1.24.0, build 0aa59064**

**Server and client host: Ubuntu 18.04**

Comment: did you restart `Docker` after setting up the Cert

Comment: Be sure to copy and accept the certificate on the server too. I made a directory under /usr/local/share/ca-certificates then copied the certificate to it and run "sudo update-ca-certificates".

Comment: @LinPy yep! I restarted the docker service.

Comment: @gile I added the ca.crt to /user/local/share/ca-certificates and the ran the command "sudo update-ca-certificates" . But nothing changed

Comment: You did it on both server and client, isn't it?

Comment: @gile I did on both server and client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found it:

I added the following line to `/var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.docker.docker`

```
/etc/docker/certs.d/** r,
```

Then I ran:

```
apparmor_parser -r /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.docker.dockerd
```

And the problem solved.